# Safe to asynchronously update a document in a Firebase Cloud Function without waiting before returning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Within my Firebase Cloud Function file I have the following local function that does a document-get and then updates it before returning some property from it.

```
async function getRandomDocLessThanOperator(seed) {
    try {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const snapshot = await db.collection("users").where("random", "<=", seed)
                                                     .limit(1)
                                                     .get();
        if (snapshot.empty) {
            return null; // caller then attempts the greater-than operator
        }
        const doc = snapshot.docs[0];
        doc.ref.update({"random": seed}); // update with new seed
        return doc.get("uid");
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}
```

This function works fine but my concern is that I attempt to update the doc asynchronously before returning. In testing, however, the document has never not updated. But could this function time out before the update is made?

In any event, to remedy this concern, I tried to `await` the update:

```
const doc = snapshot.docs[0];
await doc.ref.update({"random": seed});
return doc.get("uid");
```

However, when I did this, the function returned the string, as expected, but did not update the document.

1. Why would prepending the update with `await` prevent the update?
2. Is it safe to not await the update and do it asynchronously as in the first example?

Comment: It's recommended to `await` the update before returning. I'm not sure why it doesn't update it - maybe it's unrelated to `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why your update didn't work (perhaps you could use more logging to make it more clear what happens at runtime). But I can definitely say that with Cloud Functions, you are obliged to return a promise that resolves after **all** async work is complete (or await **every** promise you encounter), otherwise the function may be shut down before the work is complete.  This is a common mistake that developers make.

> Is it safe to not await the update and do it asynchronously as in the first example?

No, it is not "safe" because you have no guarantee that the async code will run continue to run after the function terminates.  You must return a promise that resolves only after all async work is complete.

Please read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) about this.

Comment: I just redeployed the functions and it fixed the `await` problem. How odd! In any event, I will just await patiently before returning.